# Equivalent of C++ reference type in C#

Tags: c#, char, constants

I am using a dll written in C++ in a C# application.
What is the equivalent for

1. `char const *`
2. `unsigned short`

in C#

thanks

Comment: LOADERDLL_API int CLoaderDLL::Open ( const char * pDevicePath )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A `char*` in C++ can have different meanings, e.g. a pointer to an array of bytes or an ANSI encoded null-terminated string. So it depends on the meaning of your data how the value can be marshaled to C#. The only answer that is definitively not wrong is: it's an [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx).
- A `unsigned short` in C++ is usually a 16-bit unsigned integer: [`UInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.aspx) (or `ushort` in C#).

Comment: LOADERDLL_API int CLoaderDLL::Open  (  const char *  pDevicePath   )

Comment: `pDevicePath` looks like it represents a path which would be a string. So I believe this should be marshalled as an `LPStr`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the code for your question and *I think* I got it worded better (check the intent). If so, you are looking for:

1. Either `string` or `byte[]`, depending on how the variable is used in the C code.
2. `ushort`, *assuming* `unsigned short` produced by your C compiler is 16 bits. In C#, `ushort` is always 16 bits (and `uint` is always 32 bits). Congrats to MS for finally giving us some consistency here. :)

Answer (score 0):

To call a method exposed via an DLLImport, you'll want to use the IntPtr type for pointers.

Remember in C++ char* is actually a pointer to memory, usually represented by a 4 byte int.

Comment: You often don't want to use `IntPtr` in your marshalling unless you have to (sometimes imposed by the marshaller, sometimes by the underlying usage in the C code) - whenever `byte[]` or `string` work they are safer and have more meaning.